# Android SDK Manager is not fetching packages

Tags: android-sdk

I am using Ubuntu 16.10 with AMD A8 Processor
I installed OpenJDK Java 8 and Eclipse through Terminal.
I download `android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz` and also Extract this download.
But when I run `cd /home/wini/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools` command and then `./android` command
Android SDK Manager run but it shows only one installed package 'Android SDK Tools 24.4.1', unable to fetch any other package. I also use above commands with root user also.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting instead.

Comment: pls help me if anybody knows about it.

Answer (score 0):

android command is deprecated, use sdkmanager instead. Take help from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager)