# Android SDK manager failed to run, got NullPointerException

Tags: android, ubuntu-sdk

I am using Ubuntu 16.10.I have installed OpenJDK Java 9 and Eclipse through Terminal. When I run `android` I got this error http://pastebin.com/ALEsETUC (too long to post it here) and my SDK manager just froze at "Fetching ...addons_list-2.xml". [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmJgR.png). I already remove all folders and redownload the tools file. The issue is still there.

I found another question about this same issue at [Android SDK Manager is not fetching packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838140/android-sdk-manager-is-not-fetching-packages) but there is no answer.

EDIT: Here is the error

```
(Android SDK Manager:9198): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) == G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed

(Android SDK Manager:9198): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_type_add_interface_static: assertion 'g_type_parent (interface_type) ==     G_TYPE_INTERFACE' failed
Exception in thread "Loading Sources" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurityManager.java:65)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Cipher.java:2595)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Cipher.java:2619)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isUnlimited(java.base@9-Ubuntu/CipherSuite.java:602)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<init>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/CipherSuite.java:574)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/CipherSuite.java:460)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/CipherSuite.java:1074)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableSupportedCipherSuiteList(java.base@9-Ubuntu/SSLContextImpl.java:353)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.access$100(java.base@9-Ubuntu/SSLContextImpl.java:41)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$AbstractTLSContext.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/SSLContextImpl.java:582)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Class.java:291)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Provider.java:1844)
    at java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Provider.java:1820)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@9-Ubuntu/GetInstance.java:236)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(java.base@9-Ubuntu/GetInstance.java:164)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(java.base@9-Ubuntu/SSLContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:202)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createDefaultSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.<init>(SSLSocketFactory.java:333) 
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:294)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:445)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openWithHttpClient(UrlOpener.java:369)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openUrl(UrlOpener.java:188)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:298)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:681)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:514)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetchXmlUrl(AddonsListFetcher.java:272)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetch(AddonsListFetcher.java:137)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.loadRemoteAddonsListInTask(PackageLoader.java:465)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.access$200(PackageLoader.java:52)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader$3.run(PackageLoader.java:435)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:140)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView.startTask(ProgressView.java:162)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressViewFactory.start(ProgressViewFactory.java:46)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.loadRemoteAddonsList(PackageLoader.java:432)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader$1.run(PackageLoader.java:238)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:130)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Thread.java:843)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Can not initialize cryptographic mechanism
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:91)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.normalizeAndCheck(java.base@9-Ubuntu/UnixPath.java:75)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.<init>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/UnixPath.java:69)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.getPath(java.base@9-Ubuntu/UnixFileSystem.java:280)
    at java.nio.file.Paths.get(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Paths.java:84)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.setupJurisdictionPolicies(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:254)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.access$000(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:49)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:82)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$1.run(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:79)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(java.base@9-Ubuntu/Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.<clinit>(java.base@9-Ubuntu/JceSecurity.java:78)
    ... 41 more
```

EDIT: Using `android list sdk --all` gave the same error as above

Comment: I'm just wondering but why are you using Eclipse instead of Android Studio?

Comment: I installed both Eclipse and Android Studio though. I just forgot to mention it in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 9 hasn't been released yet (for good reason) and you should expect problems. I would try downgrading to Java 8 with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and choose Java 8 (it should be openjdk-8)

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your answer.